# Dolby Atmos encoded sound in HTML file on Chrome

Tags: audio, html, web-browser, chrome

so my problem is that I came across the [license](https://developer.dolby.com/platforms/html5/browser-support/) issue with Dolby Atmos on Google Chrome.

I want to create a website where people can listen to the difference between a dolby encoded sound and a normal one. But since some browsers don't support Dolby I wonder if there is some workaround to ensure anyone can use the website?

Comment: This don't seems to be asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: I thought packages or workarounds with libraries or whatever would be a software recommendation as well xD @Alejandro

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum can you please **[edit]** your question so it's clear you're asking for a library, for which language(s) it should be, and what features it needs to cover? Then it would indeed be on-topic. Currently it rather looks like you're asking for [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [code fragments](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), which are off-topic here.